# Program encounters OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, face-detection

I am trying detect a face in a gif image but since OpenCV doesn't support gif formats, so I used PIL module to read the gif image and convert it back to a numpy array for OpenCV to use.But doing so I am getting an assertion error.

Here is my code below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# get the features and pass it to the Cascade Classifier
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
# read the image
img = Image.open("mypic.sleepy")
# check if image exists
if img is None:
    raise Exception("could not load image !")
# represent the image in matrix format for the OpenCV to work on it
img = np.array(img)
# convert it to gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# detect the objects resembling faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.5,3) #(image,scale_factor, minm_no_of_neighbours)
for face in faces:
    # the detected face is represented in the form of a rectangle
    x, y, w, h = face
    # draw a rectangle on the face in the image
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
# show the image
cv2.imshow("Detected Faces", img)
# hold the window
cv2.waitKey(0)
# destroy all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the error I am encountering

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/souvik/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 10638
```

The usual suggestion I found in the internet is that the image is not loaded and that's why it throws such error but clearly in my case the image is indeed loaded otherwise my code would throw an exception.Also If I try to run this code

```
print(img.shape)
```

I get a value of `(243, 320)`.So where am I going wrong?

Comment: The image you load is already grayscale (single channel). No need to **converto to** grayscale

Comment: @Miki You were right and I replaced it with a colored gif image but the problem still persists!

Comment: The gif is probably colormapped, i.e. single channel. Use a colored PNG, JPG or basically anything else but gif

Comment: is there a reason why you load the image with PIL and then pass it to OpenCV? basically openCV tells you that it does not have 3 or 4 channels to convert it from BGR to GRAY. BTW, PIL is RGB and not BGR in case that it is a colored image. A colored image in OpenCV has the shape (height, width, channels) so in your case it should be (243, 320, 3)

Comment: @api if I remember correctly, OpenCV can't load GIF

Comment: @Miki I have never tried that (I usually work with other type of images), good to know :)

Comment: @api55 Basically I am trying out face recognision using OpenCV and for that I am using Yale dataset which contains grayscale gif images.So I converted my images to a grayscale gif format to be on same page as the Yale dataset.So first the face must be detected before recognision and this is where it is failing.

Comment: @SouvikRay Then, if it is grey it is probably 1 channel only. As far as I remmeber PIL actually checks if it is 1 channel or 3. OpenCV always loads 3 channels by default. The answer given by Tiphel may work. You can try using the shape, if it is 3 channels then you convert else you continue without converting to grey

Comment: Then if you know that your images are always grayscale, why are you converting them from bgr to grayscale?

Comment: @Miki  The weird part is when I try out Tiphel's solution ie comment out grayscale, it works for the above code and so for the code I actually wrote for face recognision.Both the code runs without error but in the above code I get the detected faces but not for my face recognision code.Weird?

Comment: @SouvikRay What's weird about it? You're skipping the unnecessary conversion from BGR to grayscale, which failed precisely due to the fact that you already had a grayscale image. Or are you talking about a problem that's different to `cvtColor` asserting?

Comment: @DanMašek Hey my bad!I just realized the same thing.I was already passing a grayscale image and carrying out unnecessary conversion from BGR to gray.Now I passed colored gif images to the yale dataset and my face recognision works just fine and so with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code with different color gif images and using the face_cascade on `img` itself seems to work. Try to comment out the grayscale conversion and use

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img,1.5,3)
```